# jQuery ajaxy, history app not loading on localhost

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, xampp

I would like to use ajax plugin for loading content with hash change.

**LINK** to plugin webpage http://balupton.github.io/jquery-ajaxy/demo/

It is working on external server

**LINK** http://revelier.home.pl/SzymonDz/demo/

But on local how when I use xampp 3.1.0.3.1.0
Im connecting by port 8080

Normally there is no error on my server 
but locally it load only active state
and **ERROR**

```
GET http://localhost/history/demopages/bananas.html
```

Like it would lost one "/" between demo and pages -> demo/pages

Can some1 help me with this problem? 
Any help would be appreciate:)

Answer (score 0):

Solved, had to made localhost without 8080, found out which program took my 80 (thats why i had 8080). Skype , settings, advanced, ports and uncheck "use port 80 and 443". Now script work.